# SSH via Raspberry Pi's working Domain

Tags: raspbian, ssh, port-forwarding

I've got a working domain for my Raspberry Pi to which I can ping to. I forwarded the port for SSH (Port 22) on my router as well, but I still cannot connect from outside to my Raspberry.

Connecting to it via the local IP address in the local net works perfectly fine.
However, `ssh [username]@[domain]` is not working. Connection refused to port 22. I'm using Ubuntu. Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have we got any ideas? Probably.

- Try opening up your firewall using `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`
- Maybe your router (or Pi) uses DHCP and your port forward isn't valid anymore. Try running `ifconfig -a` and check the IP of your network interface (probably `eth0`).

  - Check if `inet addr` still matches the one on your port forward.
- Double-check your domain's A record. Some ISPs assign IP addresses using an address pool and DHCP. Maybe your domain's A record isn't your IP address anymore.

  - You can just ping the domain the run `curl icanhazip.com` on your Pi and check if the IP addresses match.
- Maybe your ISP is a butt and placed you behind a transparent proxy (since maybe they have a limited IP pool). This is actually the primary reason I switched ISP. Check using http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test

Comment: it doesnt work. with the "nmap" i found out that the port 22 is "closed". thats why i changed the port to be listened from 22 to 7. Surely i portforwarded port 7 as well.

i'm still not able to connect to my raspberry pi. 
ssh [name]@[domain.com] -p 7 does not work.

im out of ideas.

Comment: @Vinhi Check the last bullet.